# Почему такой вывод?

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста, почему так выводит: `0`, затем `1`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      for(var key in  {1:1, 0:0}) {
        alert(key);
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Я думал будет ошибка...

Comment: лучше вы расскажите, почему вы думали, что будет ошибка?

Comment: @DreamChild, потому, что вродебы нельзя называть свойства цифрами.

Comment: так это же мапа обычная

Comment: @VladGavriuk кто вам сказал, что "вродебы нельзя называть свойства цифрами"?

Comment: @VladGavriuk Видимо все потому, что ключами являются числа.... а они упорядочиваются по возрастанию в данном случае

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в JS ключи всегда строковые :) Синтаксис это уже совсем другой вопрос...

Comment: @D-side ну вы прогоните ключи по `isNaN` и посмотрите какие это строки =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошая попытка :} Но: `for(var key in  {1:1, 0:0}) { alert(typeof key); }`

Comment: Ответ дан: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148903/why-do-numeric-keys-in-javascript-always-sort-to-the-beginning    Переводчик только нужен